# How to filter out nodes from an XML using PERL script

Tags: xml, perl, filter, attributes, libxml2

This question is all over the internet but all the examples I see do not take into account my apparently unique circumstances. Here is an excerpt from my XML:

```
<message type="error" from="Realtime" timestamp="Mon Nov 24 19:28:55 2014"> Could not receive from Loader </message>
<message type="warning" from="Dcd_Mux" timestamp="Mon Dec  1 02:31:18 2014"> Could not connect to Dcd </message>
```

Instead of having several levels of nodes, I just have several attributes on a message node. I want to be able to filter out nodes based on an argument to my Perl script. For example: If I wanted to filter out all messages with type="error", and I was using an XML that only had the 2 lines from above, my output would only be the warning message from above. Output shown here:

```
<message type="warning" from="Dcd_Mux" timestamp="Mon Dec  1 02:31:18 2014"> Could not connect to Dcd </message>
```

I need some direction on how to begin opening the XML, looping through the entire thing, and removing any nodes that have attributes that match my filter. I'm interested in using LibXML to get this done.

Comment: I'm unclear about what you need. For instance, what should happen with `perl logview.pl -type="error"`? You say it should *"remove all messages with `type="error"`"*, but from what? Do you have a static XML data file that you want to edit?

Comment: @Borodin I've editted the question. I don't care about the arguments, per say, but to answer your comment... yes, the script is directly accessing the file to be parsed/filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [XML::LibXML](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Parser) as my XML parser.

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

die "usage\n" if @ARGV != 2;

my ($type, $qfn) = @ARGV;
my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($qfn);
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//message') {
   my $type_addr = $node->getAttribute('type');
   next if !$type_addr || $type_addr ne $type;

   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$doc->toFile($qfn);
```

Comment: I thought this was helpful, but some comments that explain what is happening might help even more. what's the qw(); at the top for?

Comment: It's the list of things to import from the module. In this case, nothing. If there's anything else that's unclear, let me know.

Comment: okay, does 'my ($type, $qfn) = @ARGV;' just assign the first argv to $type and the second to $qfn (which is the XML file)?

Comment: Yup! QFN = Qualified file name, an absolute or relative path to a file.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and comments. I got it to filter using your help. The other post was also very helpful and works for the most part. I ended up using unbindNode() instead of parentNode->removeChild($node) cuz it looks cleaner.

Comment: That's not the purpose of `unbindNode`. It's used to remove the node from the document to add it to a different document. As a result, the node isn't feed until later. If you want to simplify `$node->parentNode->removeChild($node)`, use a sub instead. `sub deleteNode { $_[0]->parentNode->removeChild($_[0]); }   deleteNode($node);`

Answer (score 2):

It could look something like this using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML):

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = $ARGV[0] 
   or die "Missing XML filename to parse";
my $type = $ARGV[1] 
   or die "Missing type of node to exclude";

open(my $xml_file, '<', $filename) 
   or die "Cannot open XML file '$filename' for reading: $!";

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => $xml_file);
NODE:
foreach my $message_node ( $dom->findnodes('/root/message') ) {
   next NODE 
      unless $message_node->hasAttribute('type');

   $message_node->unbindNode() 
      if $message_node->getAttribute('type') eq $type;
}
$dom->toFile($filename);
```

Comment: I tried parts of your solution starting from 'my $dom =' but an error was thrown stating that it 'Can't locate object method "load_xml" via package XML::LibXML'. I'm apparently using LibXML version 2.0.0.

Comment: `load_xml` is a newer method. The backwards compatible interface would be `XML::LibXML->new->parse_fh($xml_file)`.

Comment: Thank you, poster. Both your answer and another person's answer solved this for me. I chose theirs over yours because they went above and beyond (answering comments) in leading me to a combined solution.

Comment: @Borodin I like labels when I use next, last, and redo, it makes it easier for me to follow the control-flow of the program. Regardless of there only being a single level of iteration here, I still like using them. As for your comment about Java, that I don't really understand. Which pieces of the program do you have issue with? I will gladly clarify why I wrote the answer this way.

Comment: @CommanderCody No worries, it is your question; give the answer to whichever answer helps you the most

Answer (score 2):

There's two elements to your problem - first building a filter criteria, and the selecting or deleting elements based on it.

In particular - mixing 'add' and 'remove' can be quite difficult, because deciding what to do if they don't apply or contradict can be rather annoying.

Anyway, I'm offering `XML::Twig` despite that not being precisely what you've asked for - because I've used it a fair bit, and haven't really touched LibXML.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

#read these from ARGV, just here as example.
my @sample_filters = qw ( -type=error
                          -from=Not_Dcd_Mux );

my %exclude;
for (@sample_filters) {
    if (m/^-/) {
        my ( $att, $criteria ) = (
            m/^-     #starts with -
              (\w+)  #word
              =     
              (\w+)
              $      #end of string
              /x
        );
        next unless $att;
        $exclude{$att} = $criteria;
    }
}

#process_message is called for each 'message' element, and tests filters for exclusion.
sub process_message {
    my ( $twig, $message ) = @_;
    foreach my $att ( keys %exclude ) {
        if ( $message->att($att) eq $exclude{$att} ) {
            $message->delete();
            last;
        }
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => { 'message' => \&process_message }
);
$twig->parse( \*DATA ); #might use 'parsefile ( $filename )' or 'STDIN' instead
$twig->print;


__DATA__
<XML>
<message type="error" from="Realtime" timestamp="Mon Nov 24 19:28:55 2014"> Could not receive from Loader </message>
<message type="warning" from="Not_Dcd_Mux" timestamp="Mon Dec  1 02:31:18 2014"> Could not connect to Dcd </message>
<message type="warning" from="Dcd_Mux" timestamp="Mon Dec  1 02:31:18 2014"> Could not connect to Dcd </message>
</XML>
```

Comment: I editted to not include the arguments as a part of the question. I did look into XML::Twig a little bit, but I don't believe we have that installed. I know that libxml is on all machines we have. I'll dig into it further... maybe we can add it.

Comment: On the subject of XML:Twig, it comes with command-line tool `xml_grep` which could be of use if the file consists entirely of messages to be filtered

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a variation on the one from *Hunter McMillen*, and is here largely to illustrate what I meant by *"looks like a Java program written in Perl"*.

The parameter validation is part of it and, while I have reduced it to a simple count check, I would not normally write anything at all. It is of doubtful worth as the question is about how to process the data, and any such trimmings depend on who will be using the program and how often.

I have chosen to serialize the output and print it to `STDOUT`, as it is often more useful to be able to redirect output as required on the command line.

I recognized what I thought was a Java-style approach by the attention to verification and general *"protecting me from myself"*. I don't believe that adding a label and using it in `next` is at all helpful, especially with such a short loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint;

@ARGV == 2 or die <<END_USAGE;
Usage:
  $0 <XML file> <node type>
END_USAGE

my ($xml_file, $exclude_type) = @ARGV;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $xml_file);

for my $node ( $dom->findnodes('/root/message[@type]') ) {
  my $type = $node->getAttribute('type');
  $node->unbindNode if $type eq $exclude_type;
}

local $XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration = 1;
my $pp = XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint->new;
print $pp->pretty_print($dom)->toString;
```

**output**

```
<root>
  <message type="warning" from="Dcd_Mux" timestamp="Mon Dec  1 02:31:18 2014">
    Could not connect to Dcd
  </message>
</root>
```

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I have written this as an explanation of my comments on your solution. I hope it helps you to understand my thinking.