# remove XML nodes with attribute in Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I am new to Perl and I have lots of `XML` files with the same following structure:

```
<reult>
    <test name="test1">
        <meassage type="passed">
            <description><![CDATA[  ===>> passed is here]]></description>
        </meassage>
        <check name="" line="150">
            <result type="text"></result>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </check>
        <meassage type="error">
            <description><![CDATA[  ===>> error is here]]></description>
        </meassage>
        <meassage type="passed">
            <description><![CDATA[  ===>> passed is here]]></description>
        </meassage>
    </test>
    <test name="test2">
        <meassage type="warning">
            <description><![CDATA[  ===>> warning is here]]></description>
        </meassage>
        <meassage type="fail">
            <description><![CDATA[  ===>> fail is here]]></description>
        </meassage>
        <meassage type="passed">
            <description><![CDATA[  ===>> passed is here]]></description>
        </meassage>
        <check name="" line="100">
            <result type="text"></result>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </check>
    </test>
</reult>
```

What I want to do is reading each test using `for` and then delete every message nodes which is irrelevant is for me. It means, all nodes having not with "fail", "error", and "warning" as attribute must be deleted.

I started to do with deleting all children of test with message, but it will delete what it should stay. Here is the main part of code only for deleting which I could not figure out.

```
my $cut_name = 'message'; 
my $xml_file = 'test.xml';

my $mainXml = XML::Simple::Tree->new( file => $xml_file,
                        node_key => 'directory',
                        target_key => 'name');

$mainXml->cut_node($cut_name);
```

After deleting all irrelevant nodes I will save the result as a new `XML` file.
By the way, would you please let me know how I could delete nodes using [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) with attribute?

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040585/how-to-filter-out-nodes-from-an-xml-using-perl-script

Comment: Don't ever use `XML::Simple`. Try `XML::Twig` or `XML:;LibXML` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://p3rl.org/xml_grep

```
xml_grep \
    --cond 'meassage[@name="error"]' \
    --cond 'meassage[@name="fail"]' \
    --cond 'meassage[@name="warning"]' \
    so50214597.xml
```

Comment: The OP does say *"all nodes having not with "fail", "error",* ***and*** *"warning" as attribute"* but I doubt if they mean it.